# React hook for page scroll position causing re-renders on scroll

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using a React hook to track the scroll position on a page. The hook code is as follows:

```
import { useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useScrollPosition = () => {
  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(window.pageYOffset);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const updatePosition = () => {
      setScrollPosition(window.pageYOffset);
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', updatePosition);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', updatePosition);
  }, []);

  return scrollPosition;
};

export default useScrollPosition;
```

I then use this in various ways, for example in this component where a class is applied to an element if the page has scrolled more than 10px:

```
const Component = () => {
  const scrollPosition = useScrollPosition();
  const [scrolled, setScrolled] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newScrolled = scrollPosition > 10;
    if (newScrolled !== scrolled) {
      setScrolled(newScrolled);
    }
  }, [scrollPosition]);

  return (
    <div
      className={clsx(style.element, {
        [style.elementScrolled]: scrolled,
      })}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

This all works and does what I'm trying to achieve, but the component re-renders continuously on every scroll of the page.

My understanding was that by using a hook to track the scroll position, and by using useState/useEffect to only update my variable "scrolled" in the event that the scroll position passes that 10px threshold, the component shouldn't be re-rendering continuously on scroll.

Is my assumption wrong? Is this behaviour expected? Or can I improve this somehow to prevent unnecessary re-rendering? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another idea is to have your hook react only if the scroll position is over 10pixel :

```js
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

const useScrollPosition = () => {
  const [ is10, setIs10] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const updatePosition = () => {
      if (window.pageYOffset > 10)  {setIs10(true)}
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', updatePosition);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', updatePosition);
  }, []);
  
  return is10;
};

export default useScrollPosition;
```

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import useScrollPosition from "./useScrollPosition";

const Test = ({children}) => {
  const is10 = useScrollPosition();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (is10) {
      console.log('10')
    }
  }, [is10]);

  return (
    <div
      className=''
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test
```

so your component Test only renders when you reach that 10px threshold, you could even pass that threshold value as a parameter to your hook, just an idea...

Comment: Thanks, this does solve the issue. It seems I had to rethink things a little as I didn't realise that useState within the hook itself would trigger a re-render if that state wasn't connected directly to anything being rendered. Have done exactly what you said and passed the threshold to the hook which works perfectly.

Comment: happy i could help out !!

Answer (score 1):

Everytime there is useState, there will be a re-render. In your case you could try useRef to store the value instead of useState, as useRef will not trigger a new render

Comment: But I am only updating this state with "setScrolled()" occasionally, if the condition "scrollPosition > 10" changes. So surely it should only trigger a render when that condition changes, not continuously on scroll?

Comment: The component will be re-rendered every time setState is called inside the hook as well

Comment: Ah interesting, I didn't know that updating useState within the hook itself would cause a re-render even if that value is not being used to change anything on the front end. I tried useRef but then the updated value didn't get passed to the component on scroll at all. Have gone with another suggestion which does solve the problem though. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

another idea if you want to stick to your early version is a compromise :have the children of your component memoized, say you pass a children named NestedTest :

```js
import React from 'react'

const NestedTest = () => {

  console.log('hit nested')
  return (
    <div>nested</div>
  )
}

export default React.memo(NestedTest)
```

you will see that the 'hit nested' does not show in the console.
But that might not be what you are expecting in the first place. May be you should try utilizing useRef in your hook instead