# implmenting Scorll postion in reactwithout rerending the whole component?

Tags: reactjs

I want to be able to listen to scroll event to get the current value, and if the value reaches a certain threshold render a div the current logic works well with useState but it is rendering every render.
useRef however doesn't seem do be doing what is should, is there any solution to this ? will callback solve this ? if possible could you refactor to a better logic.

```js
const scrollRef = useRef<number>(0);

useEffect(() => {
  const listenToScroll = () => {
    const winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    const height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    const scrolled = winScroll / height;
    scrollRef.current = scrolled;
  };
  const fn = window.addEventListener('scroll', listenToScroll);
  return fn;
}, []);
```

Comment: i helped out recently someone with sort of the same idea : do something when you reach a certain scroll position, but avoid rerendering : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72669051/react-hook-for-page-scroll-position-causing-re-renders-on-scroll/72669450?noredirect=1#comment128362974_72669450
Let me know if it's enough or if you need additional help. The idea is to delegate this to a custom hook, wich will react only when the threshold is hit

Comment: @julBayonna even a custom hook is rerendering the whole thing...

Comment: not in the usecase i sent, because the hook is only sending back a different value when the threshold is hit, otherwise it sends the same value, wich should not rerender the component because the prop is the same.

Comment: Nice mindset behind the logic so you render only before the action happens … and then stop .. rather than keep changing all the time ….. this is the only thing I hate about react …