# Stuck at keeping the previous scroll position in React component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that loads data from API and sometimes it gets long.
I want to store user's scroll position in local storage, so that when he comes back through programmatic navigation, I can restore him to his last position.

I use this `useEffec` to store `window.scrollY` in the local storage:

```
    const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useLocalStorageState(0, 'scrollPosition')

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleScroll = () => {
            setScrollPosition(window.scrollY)
        };

        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        };
    }, []);
```

And when data is loaded, I use this code:

```
window.scroll(0, scrollPosition)
```

However, anytime user comes back to this component, the `useEffect` would kick in and saves the 0 as the new scroll position. Then my component won't be scrolled.

I'm stuck at this point. Is there a correct way to do it? Or if this is the way, how should I distinguish between the previous value and the current value?

Comment: A solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72669051/react-hook-for-page-scroll-position-causing-re-renders-on-scroll